# How to disable CodeIgniter routes for certain directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

Similar questions have been asked, but I want to find a way to do this, without changing .htaccess, but by changing routes.php.

I have wordpress installed as a subdirectory, where the root is codeigniter. So my routes.php looks like this :

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'site/dispatch/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'site/dispatch';
```

and wordpress' root is `mysite.com/blog`

If I write `mysite.com/blog`, it shows the homepage of WordPress, so no problem there,
but if I write `mysite.com/blog/post-name`, I see CodeIgniter's error page :

> An Error Was Encountered Unable to load the requested file:
>
> pages/post-name.php

So, is there a way I can configure my routes.php, so that it does not "interfere" if the url starts with `mysite.com/blog` ?

Comment: This would be better handled in your .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Codeigniter routing only directs URIs to it's own **controllers**, so you can't do this.

I agree with @Jeemusu that your `.htaccess` or any server-side routing equivalent is the appropriate option here.

Comment: I was so glad that I don't have to deal with .htaccess anymore, well, you win .htaccess, again :)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hey @jeff how did you solve this finally? I just ran into the same issue installing Codeigniter as the main app and WordPress on the /blog/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add this `$route['blog'] = "blog";` before `$route['(:any)']`

Comment: Thanks ! but it didn't change the situation. I also tried with `]="blog/";`